# Где хранить токены?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, token

Добрый день, в системе появилась необходимость интеграции с другими системами через WebApi у каждой из этих систем стоит авторизация через токены.
Токены валидны около суток.
Где правильно будет хранить эти данные?
Так что бы в случае истечения срока токена его можно было обновить.
Есть ли какое то правило на такие случаи?

Comment: Как планируете проводить интеграцию? WebAPI будет выступать в роли фасада для работы с другими системами?

Comment: у других систем имеются wepapi к которым мы обращаемся, обращение происходит непосредственно на серверной части, из бэкенда

Comment: Если в Вашем интеграторе должен быть предусмотрен механизм логирования, то можете хранить токены в БД, если это просто "сквозной" сервис, то один из вариантов - хранить токены в сериализованных в xml объектах, содержащими, как минимум три поля: значение токена, имя сервиса, дату последнего обновления.

Answer (score 1):

Можете хранить токены в xml-файле, создаваемом путём сериализации коллекции объектов класса, описывающего информацию о токене. Класс может выглядеть примерно так:

```
[Serializable]
    public class TokenInfo
    {        
        [DataMember]
        private String _value;
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Origin { get; set; }

        private TokenInfo() { }

        public TokenInfo(String origin, String value)
        {
            this.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            this._value = value;
            this.Origin = origin;
        }

        public String Value
        {
            get { return this._value; }

            set
            {
                if (value != this._value)
                { 
                    this._value = value;
                    this.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"ORIGIN: {this.Origin} | VALUE: {this._value} | UPDATED AT: {this.LastUpdated}";
        }
    }
```

Доступ к файлу и коллекции токенов можно организовать через `Singleton`. Как вариант, код класса может быть таким:

```
public class TokenStore
    {
        private static readonly Object lockObject = new Object();
        private static TokenStore _instance;
        private List<TokenInfo> _tokenCollection;
        private TokenStore()
        {
            this._tokenCollection = new List<TokenInfo>();
        }

        public static TokenStore Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                    _instance = new TokenStore();
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        public TokenInfo GetTokenForOrigin(String origin)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(@"d:\tokenStore.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TokenInfo>));
                    this._tokenCollection = (List<TokenInfo>)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
                }

                var result = this._tokenCollection.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Origin == origin);
                if (result == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Token for origin \"{origin}\" is not found.");
                else
                    return result;
            }
        }

        public void AddOrUpdateToken(TokenInfo token)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {   
                var existingToken = this._tokenCollection.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Origin == token.Origin);

                if(existingToken != null)
                {
                    this._tokenCollection.Remove(existingToken);                    
                }

                this._tokenCollection.Add(token);

                using (var fs = new FileStream(@"d:\tokenStore.xml", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TokenInfo>));
                    serializer.Serialize(fs, this._tokenCollection);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ну и, собственно, пример использования самого класса:

```
            var origin = "example.com:8080/api";
            var token = "WASD123";

            var t = new TokenInfo(origin, token);

            TokenStore.Instance.AddOrUpdateToken(t);

            Console.WriteLine(TokenStore.Instance.GetTokenForOrigin(origin));
            Console.Read();

            t.Value = "ASDW124";

            TokenStore.Instance.AddOrUpdateToken(t);
```

Comment: спасибо большое, но у меня вопрос почему для работы с файлом используется Singleton?

Comment: Так вы будете уверены, что к файлу, который хранит токены осуществляется доступ строго из одного места (из единственного экземпляра класа, отвечающего за работу с токенами) и одновременно только из одного потока за счёт того, что такой вариант Синглтона будет потокобезопасным.

Comment: понял спасибо, а все таки для таких случаев существует какое то общее правило ? я имею ввиду в плане безопасности хранения токенов.

Comment: Ну вы можете, в принципе добавить механизм шифрования в код класса, но имеет ли это смысл. Главное - защищайте сервер, чтобы никто не мог спонтанно зайти и скачать этот файл)

Comment: а вот кстати акутальная проблема для меня) есть ли хорошие туториалы по защите файлов на сервере ?

Comment: Не подскажу, это скорее походит на отдельный вопрос. Возможно в сообщество для системных администраторов)